# Library using method not implemented in Android yet

Tags: java, android, milo

I am using the Java Library Milo to implement an OPC UA client.
Connecting to the server and reading a node works fine. But when trying to subscribe to a node, I get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

The method causing this problem is `BigInteger.longValueExact()`. The reason is, that this method is not implemented in Android yet. It is used by the milo library, that I use for OPC UA.
As it is used by the library I also cannot change the method. I had a look in the documentation and `longValueExact()` will be added in Android 12.

Until Android 12 is released, is there any way for me to workaround this issue / tell Android Studio what to do when seeing this method?

The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartpremix.smartpremixapp, PID: 14350
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method longValueExact()J in class Ljava/math/BigInteger; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.math.BigInteger' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaSubscriptionManager.getLifetimeCount(OpcUaSubscriptionManager.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaSubscriptionManager.lambda$LUctLZChikw3npQWbJvSPICy8NM(Unknown Source:0)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.-$$Lambda$OpcUaSubscriptionManager$LUctLZChikw3npQWbJvSPICy8NM.apply(Unknown Source:10)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaSubscriptionManager.createSubscription(OpcUaSubscriptionManager.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaSubscriptionManager.createSubscription(OpcUaSubscriptionManager.java:110)
        at com.smartpremix.smartpremixapp.Utilities.OpcUaManager.subscribeToNode(OpcUaManager.java:96)
        at com.smartpremix.smartpremixapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```